# Reading JSON from Arduino over serial in python and writing to a JSON file on computer

Tags: python, json, arduino, pyserial

I'm fairly new to Arduino so I used a sample code before integrating this into my main code. I'm printing my value in a JSON format over serial. My Arduino outputs this and the python receives this and prints it in the same format

```
{

"value" : 5

}
```

but when I use python to try writing to a JSON file on my computer, I'm not getting the same JSON format. Can anyone figure out what's wrong? Right now, I'm looking to read from the serial using python and write that to the JSON. However, I'm also looking to read the JSON file for any changes and send that to the Arduino at the same time. For example, if the JSON file changes a certain value for a certain key, the python should communicate that to the Arduino and the Arduino executes some functions based on that value. Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Arduino Code:

```
#include <ArduinoJson.h>

int analogPin = 3;     
int data = 0; 
char userInput;          

StaticJsonDocument<100> testDocument;
char buffer[100];

void setup(){

  Serial.begin(9600);          //  setup serial

  StaticJsonDocument<100> testDocument;

  testDocument["sensorType"] = "Temperature";
  testDocument["value"] = 10;

  char buffer[100];

  serializeJsonPretty(testDocument, buffer);

  Serial.println(buffer);

}
int(i)=1;
void loop(){

    testDocument["value"] = i;

    serializeJsonPretty(testDocument, buffer);

    Serial.println(buffer);

    i=i+1;
 }
```

Python Code:

```
import serial
import json
import time

ser = serial.Serial('COM4', baudrate = 9600, timeout=1)

while 1:

    data = (ser.readline().decode('ascii')) #split('\r\n')

    #j = json.loads(data)


    file = "C:/Users/Mike/Desktop/test.json"

    my_data_file = open(file, 'w')

    with open(file1, "w") as my_data_file :
        json.dump(data, my_data_file)

    print(data)
```